# Method not even called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a class that extends `UITableViewController` and implements `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

I have defined (.h) a method:

```
-(void)populateDataWithCompletitionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completitionHandler usingCustomParser:(void(^)(NSArray* result))parser;
```

and implemented it:

```
-(void)populateDataWithCompletitionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completitionHandler usingCustomParser:(void (^)(NSArray *))parser
{
    __weak FetchedViewController *weakSelf = self;

   [self.webserviceCall setSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *result) {
       if (parser == nil) {
          // Parse success
       } else {
           parser(result);
       }
   }];

    [self.webserviceCall setFailureBlock:^{
        if (completitionHandler) {
            // Error management
        }
    }];

    [self.webserviceCall startAsynchronus];
}
```

In `WebserviceCall` class I have (in .h):

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void(^successBlock)(NSArray *result);
@property (copy, nonatomic) void(^failureBlock)(void);
```

I have noticed that sometimes `startAsynchronus` is called and sometime it is not. I have placed a breakpoint on it and another in the method.

Sometimes the method is called (and my app works) and sometimes after the call `startAsynchronus` is not called.

**startAsynchronus**

```
-(void)startAsynchronus
{    
    [_sessionManager GET:_method parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        self.successBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"*** Request error %@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    //[task resume];
}
```

**I Think this is the solution **

Looking on my viewWillAppear method i was wrote this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([[User sharedInstance] isLoggedIn]) {
        BOOL entityIsSync = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:_item.entity];

        if (!entityIsSync) {
            self.webserviceCall = [[WebserviceCall alloc] initWithMethod:_item.method forEntity:_item.entity];
            [self populateDataWithCompletitionHandler:nil usingCustomParser:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

This line MUST be outside the if statement:

```
self.webserviceCall = [[WebserviceCall alloc] initWithMethod:_item.method forEntity:_item.entity];
```

But i have another question: Why if self.webservice call was null, i will not get any error (at runtime).

Comment: It looks like you've mis-spelled `startAsynchronous` (you're calling it as `startAsynchronus`).

Comment: Sorry i have wrote wrong. The method that i have defined is "startAsynchronus" and i call "startAsynchronus" (if not i will get a compiler error :-) )

Comment: The title of this question is that the block is not called, but in your question you say that startAsynchronous is not called. What exactly is the issue? The actual order of operations here when the app runs is the success block is first set, the failure block is then set, then the startAsycnhronous method is run, and at some future point either the success or failure block is called. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: On WebserviceCall i have declared the two block and in populateDataWithCompletitionHandler i define them. When this method is executed all two block will be set but startAsynchronous sometime will be called and sometime not. Placing a breakpoint on [self.webserviceCall startAsynchronus]; and another inside startAsynchronus, sometime i see the "compiler" jump inside it, and sometime "skip" it.

Comment: Can you show the startAsynchronous method?

Comment: I have added it on original post, and i have added another note that probably is the solution for my problem.